# How to create a page with the selected template after activating the plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm writing my first plugin and I have problem. I don't know how to write function, which create page with selected specific template after activate plugin.

```
function add_my_custom_page() {
    // Create post object
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( 'Example form' ),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_type'     => 'page',
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'add_my_custom_page');

add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpa3396_page_template' );
function wpa3396_page_template( $page_template )
{
    if ( is_page( 'my-custom-page-slug' ) ) {
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/form/haccp-form.php';
    }
    return $page_template;
}
```

Comment: What if the user with the ID `1` was deleted? Then this page would have an author that doesn't exist! Have you considered instead addng a rewrite rule then loading the template when it matches? There's no need for a post or page in the database if yoou're adding something with a known URL

Comment: @ncti it's helpful to add some description of where it goes wrong - what have you tried to debug your code? That looks like a valid call to wp_insert_post, so did you check if it ran or not? What happens if you run that code another way (on another hook for example), does it work to add a page like that?

Comment: @TomJNowell could you explain me how to do it?

Comment: @mozboz it's working but not perfectly. Page which is being created is not set template